# Photoshop CC: convert to frame timeline releases only one frame

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, adobe-after-effects, jpg

I have a 20 second animation brought in from After Effects as a jpeg sequence. When I import it, it makes a video timeline, but I need to delete individual repeat frames so I can add a delay to reduce the size of the finished animated GIF. But when I convert from video timeline to frame timeline only one frame results.

How can I get an old-school frame layout for my imported animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually discovered this solution, hope it helps somebody:

- timeline > convert frames > flatten frames into clips
- timeline > convert frames > make frames from clips
- delete video group at bottom (to leave multiple layers)
- convert to frame animation

Comment: Perfect solution. Should be the accepted answer. Worked in Photoshop CC 2017.